# Removing horizontal bands from image with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I´ve got a problem with a video image that im trying to capture and process in my pc.

The thing is that the video camera is wireless, so the video images that im getting have horizontal bands due to interferences or whatever it is causing this.

What i want to do is to try and remove the horizontal bands from the image to try to get the clearer image possible.

Is there any algorithm or method to do this? The algorithm has to be adaptative because the bands are not always the same. Im trying to accomplish this with opencv in c++, but I´m having trouble finding anything in this subject.

Thanks.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659958/remove-horizontal-lines-from-the-image-using-opencv). No actual answers, but link to [article](http://tpgit.github.io/UnOfficialLeptDocs/leptonica/line-removal.html). Don't know if the technique is easily translated to opencv.

Comment: I have seen that article, but I don´t know if my problem (and solution) is the same. Here is a link to the image and the problem that I have: http://i39.tinypic.com/2qk6stu.jpg

Answer (score 0):

you should figure out what the real cause of these bands are and fix it. for any kind of image processing, bands like that will minimise what you can actually do with an image. you won't be able to replace the bands with what should have been there.